# Cannot deploy war with elasticsearch dependency on lifray portlet

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jboss, liferay, liferay-6

I use lifray 6.2 with jboss 7.1.1.
I cannot deploy war with my portlet were I use elasticsearch dependencies

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>5.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
  <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
  <version>5.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It shows me warnings for all classes of ES while deployment "Could not index class ..." What should I do to deploy my portlet without these warnings with working ES

```
11:48:24,878 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015852: Could not index class org/elasticsearch/percolator/PercolatorPlugin.class at /D:/ADIDAS/liferay/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2/jboss-7.1.1/standalone/deployments/mp-services-portlet.war/WEB-INF/lib/percolator-client-5.4.0.jar: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag! pos=18 poolCount = 185
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are using a not right versions of dependecy , its important to see version of jdk , liferay ect ,, here is a link to resolve this -- https://web.liferay.com/it/marketplace/-/mp/application/41044606
hope is useful !!